# MemoryFailPoint always throws an InsufficientMemoryException even when memory is available

Tags: c#, memory-management, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I have written the following code to check for sufficient memory,

```
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        // Check for available memory.
        memFailPoint = new MemoryFailPoint(250);

        break;
    }
    catch (InsufficientMemoryException ex)
    {
        if (memFailPoint != null)
        {
          memFailPoint.Dispose();
        }

        Thread.Sleep(waitSecond * 1000);
    }
}
```

I am running the above in a console application on a Windows 7 64-bit machine.

There are 4 calls every 10 seconds to this method.

Initially it works fine, but after 2-3 hours, there is always an `InsufficientMemoryException` thrown. I checked available memory and it shows more than 1 GB.

I tried a lot but I was not able to find why this is happening.

Following is the stack trace:

```
at System.Runtime.MemoryFailPoint..ctor(Int32 sizeInMegabytes)
at SocketListner.AcceptConnection(IAsyncResult res) in H:\Projects\SocketListner.cs:line 308
```

There is no inner exception.

Comment: What else are you doing to get this error?  Is there a stack trace you can post?

Comment: I have added stack trace , please revisit question

Comment: "I checked available memory" how? Even with 1GB free, it may be too fragmented to make an allocation of 250Meg. There would need to be 250M contiguous space free in the memory for this to succeed.

Comment: Doesn't matter how much physical memory or even virtual memory is left. How much memory is in use by your process?

Comment: I checked in Resource Monitor

Comment: That's a huge amount to need to allocate. Does it actually reflect your allocation needs? You'd need to allocate a very large array for this to be reflective of such a big allocation. If you intend to create lots of smaller objects, then testing for 250Meg is a bad approach.

Comment: @spender Actually this is a TCP Listener, it receives 4 1MB packet every 10 seconds, and processing takes 20 times memory for a packet. I release memoryFailPoint after receiving packet. Can you help me to implement it proper way.

Comment: Even if it takes 20 times memory for a packet, this memory doesn't have to be consecutive, does it ?

Comment: I think yes, once a packet is processed memory should be free, but for after long time Database becomes bottleneck and data stay in memory upto timeout i.e. 30 seconds

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can rely on this method working correctly, this exception is **very** likely to trip in a 32-bit process when you ask for 250 megabytes.  That gets to be difficult to get when the program has been running for a while.

A program *never* crashes with OOM because you've consumed all available virtual memory address space.  It crashes because there isn't a hole left in the address space that's big enough to fit the allocation.  Your code requests a hole big enough to allocate 250 megabytes in one gulp.   When you don't get the exception that you can be sure that this allocation will not fail.

But 250 megabytes is rather a lot, that's a really big array.  And is very likely to fail due to a problem called "address space fragmentation".  In other words, a program typically starts out with several very large holes, the largest about 600 megabytes.  Holes available between the allocations made to store code and data that's used by the .NET runtime and unmanaged Windows DLLs.  As the program allocates more memory, those holes get smaller.  It is likely to release some memory but that doesn't reproduce a big hole.  You typically get *two* holes, roughly half the size of the original, with an allocation somewhere in the middle that cuts the original big hole in two.

This is called *fragmentation*, a 32-bit process that allocates and releases a lot of  memory ends up fragmenting the virtual memory address space so the biggest hole that's still available after a while gets smaller, around 90 megabytes is fairly typical.  Asking for 250 megabytes is almost guaranteed to fail.  You will need to aim lower.

You no doubt expected it to work differently, ensuring that the *sum* of allocations adding up to 250 megabytes is guaranteed to work.  This however is not how MemoryFailPoint works, it only checks for the *largest* possible allocation.  Needless to say perhaps, this makes it less than useful.  I otherwise do sympathize with the .NET framework programmers, getting it to work the way we'd like it is both expensive and cannot actually provide a guarantee since the size of an allocation matters most.

Virtual memory is a plentiful resource that's incredibly cheap.  But getting close to consuming it all is very troublesome.  Once you consume a gigabyte of it then OOM striking at random is starting to get likely.  Don't forget the easy fix for this problem, you are running on a 64-bit operating system.  So just changing the EXE platform target to AnyCPU gets you gobs and gobs of virtual address space.  Depends on the OS edition but a terabyte is possible.  It still fragments but you just don't care anymore, the holes are huge.

Last but not least, visible in the comments, this problem has **nothing** to do with RAM.  Virtual memory is quite unrelated to how much RAM you have.  It is the operating system's job to map virtual memory addresses  to physical addresses in RAM, it does so dynamically.  Accessing a memory location may trip a page fault, the OS will allocate RAM for the page.  And the reverse happens, the OS will unmap RAM for a page when it is needed elsewhere.  You can never run out of RAM, the machine will slow down to a crawl before that can happen.  The SysInternals' VMMap utility is nice to see what your program's virtual address space looks like, albeit that you tend to drown in the info for a large process.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed analysis and suggessions. I've decreased the size to 50MB and put the app in testing, however I made build in 64bit so OOM exception should not occur, as it was caught earlier.

Comment: I have to say, just arbitrarily cutting it from 250 to 50 is rather random.  It is important that the number you pick has some truth and represents the amount of memory you are going to need.

Comment: how to know that?, once a packet is processed memory should be free, but for after long time Database becomes bottleneck and data stay in memory upto timeout i.e. 30 seconds.

Comment: If you have no idea then gathering evidence with a memory profiler is important.  The VMMap utility I mentioned is a cheap version of that.  Experimenting with the value you pass to MemoryFailPoint is the long way to get there.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the `GC.GetTotalMemory` method to determine the amount of memory available  before and after calling:

```
memFailPoint = new MemoryFailPoint(250);
```

`InsufficientMemoryException` is thrown before starting an operation, by the `MemoryFailPoint` constructor when you specify a projected memory allocation larger than the amount of currently available memory.
Like user7116 [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17046463/memoryfailpoint-always-throws-insufficientmemoryexception-even-when-memroy-is-av#comment24644837_17046463), that's why you should check first.

The example in this link should give you a solution: [MemoryFailPoint Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.memoryfailpoint.aspx)

You can also check this msdn blog article: [Out of memory? Easy ways to increase the memory available to your program](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/calvin_hsia/archive/2010/09/27/10068359.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

MemoryFailPoint checks for consecutive available memory as documented here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.runtime.memoryfailpoint.aspx

You may consume very little memory, but have fragmented it a lot and then be now unable to allocate a consecutive block of memory of the needed size. It's very typical of this problem to occur after a few hours. To avoid that, use a pool of object for object you keep instantiating, it will make the  memory space in use more rigid.