# Prevent "Out of Memory" exception on filling huge number of data from SQL database

Tags: .net, sql-server

How to prevent "Out of Memory" exception when filling huge number of data with sqldata adapter.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sqlDataAdapter daTest = new sqlDataAdaptor("select * from dailyattendance",sqlconn);
daTest.fill(dt);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should try paging your results to avoid loading all the data at once.
[MSDN example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/paging-through-a-query-result):

```
orderSQL = "SELECT TOP " + pageSize +   
  " * FROM Orders WHERE OrderID > " + lastRecord + " ORDER BY OrderID";  
adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = orderSQL;  

dataSet.Tables["Orders"].Rows.Clear();  

adapter.Fill(dataSet, "Orders");
```

Here is the example for SQL server 2012+ mentioned by @Scott

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dailyattendance]
OFFSET @PageSize * (@PageNumber - 1) ROWS
FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY;
```

You have to use [parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) hereto populate `@PageSize` and `@PageNumber`

Comment: Sigh, i really wish they had used parametrized queries in that examle, the query could be expressed by `"SELECT top (@pageSize) * FROM Orders WHERE OrderID > @lastRecord ORDER BY OrderID"`, the parenthesis around `@pageSize` is important, you will get a syntax error without it.

Comment: How do i do to select the next following record since the MSSQL do not allow to do as MYSQL "Limit (0,100)

Comment: yes, that is possible and this example is for MS SQL i guess. @Scott provided the example which is better in terms of security. When you will manage to do the simple one you should investigate the parameters usage.

Comment: @JimLim You select the next record by setting `lastRecord` to be the last `OrderID` from the previous result set. Also, if you want the MYSQL style in SQL2012 and newer you can use the `OFFESET` and `FETCH` keywords to a similar syntax. https://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/pagination-with-offset-fetch

Answer (score 0):

I second Michael's answer as we should page the result and get it loaded. But was thinking about the scenario where we need to load everything to memory for some processing.In that case you can use [**MemoryFailPoint Class**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.memoryfailpoint.aspx)

```
try
 {
  using (MemoryFailPoint point = new MemoryFailPoint(100000))
   {
    // An exception is thrown at this point.
    //  does not have enough memory.
    // We can do our datatable operation here
    }
   }
  catch (InsufficientMemoryException e)
  {
    // MemoryFailPoint threw an exception
   }
```

> Creating an instance of the MemoryFailPoint class creates a memory
>   gate. A memory gate checks for sufficient resources before initiating
>   an activity that requires a large amount of memory. Failing the check
>   results in an InsufficientMemoryException exception being thrown. This
>   exception prevents an operation from being started and reduces the
>   possibility of failure due to lack of resources. This enables you
>   decrease performance to avoid an OutOfMemoryException exception and
>   any state corruption that may result from improper handling of the
>   exception in arbitrary locations in your code.

Please note that MemoryFailPoint is far from perfect ,more details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35731975/how-do-i-use-memoryfailpoint) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17046463/memoryfailpoint-always-throws-an-insufficientmemoryexception-even-when-memory-is)

Comment: Thank , Rajan. You have provided a helpful tips.